# Suitable Design Pattern for Multi Threaded Java Application

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, design-patterns, design-principles

I am a newbie to java technology and have a little idea about design patterns. I have to write a java application that contains 3 independent threads:

- the first thread is used to write on a file "A"
- the second one is used to write on a file "B"
- and when the writing on file done an another independent thread "C" merge these two file.

I have to write the application as efficient as possible. I am thinking about using design pattern. Is there any design pattern that fits the scenario best?

Comment: First things first - do you have an SSD or hardware RAID array? If not then writing two files at once will be _slower_ than writing one. Second, have you tried anything? If so post it.

Comment: I would [read this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-definitive-guide) to get an idea of where to start.

Comment: Your question sounds like homework. Is it?

Comment: @BoristheSpider This [link at Tomasz Nurkiewicz' site](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html) gives a more faithful representation (there are missing parts in the link you cited).